# How to transfer large binary files in wsfcpp

Tags: c++, file, caching, wso2, mtom

While using WSFCPP to implement Web Service I have encountered a problem at transferring large binary files. This problem was handled on the website of WSFCPP "[Common Attachment Configurations - File Caching](http://wso2.org/library/264)".

```
options.setProperty(Constants.Configuration.CACHE_ATTACHMENTS,
Constants.VALUE_TRUE);

options.setProperty(Constants.Configuration.ATTACHMENT_TEMP_DIR,TempDir);
```

However the sample code is in java. How can I get it in C++?